# Is there any benefit to changing the values of the session properties only where necessary?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I noticed how some people do this. It got me wondering if it is beneficial. For instance, I check if a given condition is met by either of the properties of a session. Then this is done again, separately for each property of the object.

Let's say I have two counters. Once one of them exceeds 1, both should get reset:

```
let notes = [];
if (req.session.counters[0] > 1 || req.session.counters[1] > 1) {
    notes.push("A counter has exceeded the limit.");
    if (req.session.counters[0] > 1) {
        req.session.counters[0] = 0;
    }
    if (req.session.counters[1] > 1) {
        req.session.counters[1] = 0;
    }
}
```

It is pretty much the same as this:

```
let notes = [];
if (req.session.counters[0] > 1 || req.session.counters[1] > 1) {
    notes.push("A counter has exceeded the limit.");
    req.session.counters[0] = 0;
    req.session.counters[1] = 0;
}
```

So, is there any benefit? Such as faster execution? Or it's pretty much pointless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In your first example, if* `counters[0] === 5` *and* `counters[1] === 0.5`*, after the if-statement,* `counters[0] === 0` *and* `counters[1] === 0.5` *while in the second example, both would be 0. This doesn't matter if the counter can't go negative or be a fractional value.*

---

Ignoring that, it would depend on how your session values are persisted.

If you have a single server, you might store the values in memory. In that case, there is no reason to use example #1.

If you are using multiple servers & users can hop between them but should have the same session, then values should be persisted in a database/a key-value store. All servers would read values from that database/key-value store. Writing a single integer is very little overhead, no matter what database you're using but if you had larger writes, example #1 might be worth it. Writing to disk or—"even worse"—to the network is a lot slower than memory.

It depends on your application if readability trumps a micro-optimization. While veering towards an opinion-based answer, I'd say in this case it absolutely does.

Comment: I just realised how confusing my example can be. It didn't cross my mind that the first snippet can result in something different. Other than that, thank you for the detailed response.